# Typesafe Activator Futures timed out after [6 seconds]

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I downloaded the latest Typesafe Activator program.  When I try to create new project, I always receive timeout.  Not sure when this can be fixed.  Is there any work around for now?

Futures timed out after [6 seconds]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [6 seconds]

Comment: When does this problem occur exactly? Please state the exact steps you followed to get this error.

Comment: when I typed in the project name after activate new command.

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/221

Answer (score 0):

The latest Activator release should fix this: http://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted